# Is there a way to stop 'yes' command after certain prompts

Tags: bash

Hi I have a script which requires 4 yes inputs by the user while the 5th prompt requires a number.

Is there a way to stop yes command after 4 'yes' so that 5th prompt is free for user to enter a number.

Comment: Instead of using yes command just echo yes four times.  Show us the command you are actually running.

Comment: `yes | head -n 4`

Answer (score 5):

You can simply pass the required input instead:

```
printf '%s\n' 'yes' 'yes' 'yes' 'yes' '1234' | ./my_script.sh
```

PS: If it's your own script I would very much recommend making it non-interactive. `./my_script.sh --enable-foo --run-bar --do-baz --include-ban --repeat 1234` (or `--foo` etc.) is longer but is enormously more expressive and therefore maintainable.

Comment: Good answer, I wasn't aware of the repeating nature of `printf`, I would have just used `printf 'yes\nyes\nyes\nyes\1234\n'`. BTW, since those items don't contain white space, you can get away with not quoting them (other than the format string).

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm well aware of quoting rules, and it's generally a bad idea to omit them.

Comment: I was just saying that, for this case, it's totally unnecessary and in *no* way a bad idea. It *sounds* like you've taken offence to my suggestion, which was not my intent, so I'll just move on.

Comment: @paxdiablo No offense taken, but I consider it a bad idea for two reasons: first, because it's entirely non-obvious to a beginner why adding for example an ampersand to a string should cause problems, and second because it clarifies what the author was trying to do.